# how to config tomcat to serve xml files directly

Tags: xml, tomcat, sitemap, catalina

I build an application which uses angular.js as frontend and spring as backend. my problem is that catalina doesn't serve xml files directly (it's okay with html or txt files but not xml) so it goes to my angular app and it returns 404 .
How can i config catalina to serve file if exist and after that pass urls to angular?
something like `try_files` in nginx:

`try_files /path/to/$1 /any/dir/$1 @your404;`

Answer (score 0):

There was a rewrite that i was not aware of, seems tomcat does actually serve files by default without any other configuration.